# Dropdown click causes focus to next control

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have form with many textbox and select tags. When i click the select tag its not opening the dropdown menu instead it move focus to next control that i have not selected.

This issue occurs only in iPhone.

Please anyone help me to solve this.one.

Answer (score 0):

To Stop automatically closing dropdown issue or stop switching to other element issue  use
 **preventDefault()** method in touch event of the select element.

Example

```
 $("#dropDownID").on('touchstart', function (e) {           
  e.preventDefault();
  });
```